# How to handle DataIntegrityViolationException to get the specific cause?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

i'm working on a java web app. The App is a REST style backend. I'm using spring mvc as my web framework and JPA/Hibernate for the persistance. The database is mysql.

I have a table in the database, where i store a simple text value with an id. So i have two columns there. However i want to make those text values unique. Already set this in sql.

Now I'm writing a unittest to handle what happens when somebody tries to insert the same string multiple times. Spring returns me a DataIntegrityViolationException. The root cause is a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException. From the root cause i can get the sqlErrorCode.

But is there a better way to handle this? Because i don't want to have the dependecy to the mysqlexception and there error code in my code.

Comment: Do you really need to look at the root cause? An data integrity constraint violation in a 2 column table can't be much else? And if you do, you could have  a translation mechanism close to the data layer that rethrows this as a custom exception of yours so the code you're concerned with doesn't need to depend on a specific datastore type or library.

Comment: The translation mechanism was my solution at the moment. But i guess your right about that i can't be much else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it inconvenient to search the DB exceptions wrapped by spring data for their root cause. I would manually check for uniqueness before persisting the new entry to the database.

Remember, the exception thrown by spring is a `RuntimeException`, and you should not handle `RuntimeException`s as these indicate a "bug" in the code. It's your responsibility that this excpetion is never thrown in the first place.

Comment: Thats the better approach. So I don't have to bother with the Mysql details.

Comment: It seems I not found anything else.